# opening new window in PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to open a new window in PHP by echoing what i need, because im placing information from my database in the URL.

I can get this to work in plain HTML, JS but as soon as i try and echo out the line it doesnt call the function, im sure im missing something obvious.

Got the code from here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Thanks

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=600');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}

// -->
</script>


<?php
 echo "<a href = 'popupex.html' onClick='return popitup(\'popupex.html\')'‌​>234</a>"; 
?>
```

Comment: I think you must not use onClick and replace ' par " and keep ' around popupex.html

Comment: FYI: You've got 2 hidden characters before your `>` in `)'‌​>234` so that could contribute to the problem.

Comment: Leaving in the `language` attribute and the `<!-- -->` comments around your JavaScript file makes it look like a dinosaur from the 1990s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had two hidden characters before your `>` in `)'‌​>234` which could contribute to the problem. (**Consult Footnotes**).

Plus, I replaced `(\'popupex.html\')` to `(\"popupex.html\")` with escaped double quotes. Leaving them as single quotes did not make the window to pop up when testing.

The two hidden characters: `&#8204;&#8203;`

**This works** with both hidden characters removed. (**tested**)

Copy the code below, do not replace with what you already have.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=600');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}

// -->
</script>


<?php
 echo "<a href = 'popupex.html' onClick='return popitup(\"popupex.html\")'>234</a>"; 
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Leaving the hidden characters in the code would show up as this in the HTML source:

`'??>234`

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=600');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
// -->
</script>

<?php
 echo "<a href = 'popupex.html' onClick='return popitup(\"popupex.html\")'‌​>234</a>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

if(something): //if you received data from database

//here you can also add value from database 
$phpvalue = "data from database";

//you can popup php value or just add your target url instead of $phpvalue

?>

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('<?=$phpvalue?>','','width=590,height=610,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,menubar=no,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes'))">Test</a>

<?php else: 
if(SOMETHINGELSE)
?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Code only answer are proved to be less useful. Try to explain what you are doing to enhance your answer

Comment: Is this ok Andrea? :)